# Is this induction proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra rigorous?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, proof-verification

I was trying to find a suitable proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra at an undergraduate level which avoided abstract linear algebra, as I have not yet begun it. However, I came across this

http://www.math.washington.edu/~aloveles/ArchivedMaterials/Math300/FundamentalTheoremOfAlgebra.pdf

which is seemingly comprehensible and straightforward, and logical but I was wondering if it is rigourous or even valid?

Comment: Yes, it contains a correct proof of the statement **A polynomial of degree d has at most d real roots.** But *that's not what most people mean by the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra*.

Comment: On the other hand, this statement can actually be considered both fundamental and of algebra, unlike the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra...

Comment: @Reinhild Van Rosenú: “This theorem is the more extraordinary that complex numbers were invented for attributing roots to the quadratic equations only” ....... “can not prove this theorem without recourse one or another way to own considerations in the analysis and not algebra” (Godement).

Comment: @Ataulfo I guess the name is a complete misnomer.

Comment: @ReinhildVanRosenú: What´is misnomer? Ataulfo was a barbarian king and it is clearly a nickname. However Godement is the great mathematician Roger Godement.

Comment: @Ataulfo Nooo, I meant the name of the theorem "The Fundamental Theorem Of Algebra", since it can't cosntructively be proved solely using algebra.

Comment: @ReinhildVanRosenú: My English is primitive. I want to say, my replica was unbiased. The fact that $\mathbb {C}$ is algebraically closed is fondamental indeed and concerns Algebra; That the proof requires analysis is perhaps an old and involuntary argument for the unity of mathematics (a modern point of view).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the one of the more accessible proof of Fundamental Theorem of Algebra is the following argument (due to Lagrange). I learned it from Pierre Samuel's *Algebraic Theory of Numbers*. It uses induction on the highest power of $2$ dividing the degree of $f$.

Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$. We need to show that $f(x)$ has exactly $d=\deg(f)$ roots. It suffices to show that every polynomial has *some* root in $\mathbb{C}$. Because then we can factor $f(x)=(x-a_1) f_1(x)$ (where $a_1$ is a root of $f(x)$), and then apply the same argument to $f_1(x)$ to get $f_1(x)=(x-a_2)f_2(x)$. Doing this $d$ times (formally: we use induction) would give $f(x)=(x-a_1)\cdots (x-a_{d})$.

Okay, so let's show that $f(x)$ has some complex root. We might as well assume $f$ is monic, i.e. $f(x)=x^{d}+\mathsf{lower \ order \ terms}$. By replacing $f(x)$ by $f(x)\overline{f(\overline{x})}$ where $\overline{z}$ is the complex conjugation, it suffices to assume that $f(x)$ has real coefficients. This is because $f(x)$ and $f(x)\overline{f(\overline{x})}$ have same roots, but the latter polynomial has real coefficients! Indeed, if $f(x)=a_d x^{d}+\cdots + a_1 x + a_0$, then $\overline{f(\overline{x})} = \overline{a_d} x^{d}+\cdots + \overline{a_1} x + \overline{a_0}$, so their product will have real coefficients.

We write $d=\deg(f)=2^{n} m$ where $m$ is odd, and proceed by induction on $n$. When $n=0$, the degree $\deg(f)$ is odd. By intermediate value theorem, it is easy to see that $f$ has a real root. Indeed, $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to-\infty} f(x) =-\infty$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=\infty$. So $f$ must cross the real axis (thereby achieving a zero) at some point. Now we assume the induction hypothesis for the case $n-1$. A theorem from field theory tells us that $f$ has some splitting field, meaning that we can find some bigger field $K$ (containing $\mathbb{C}$) over which $f$ has $d=2^{n}m$ roots, say $x_1, x_2, …, x_d\in K$ (in reality, $K=\mathbb{C}$, and that's exactly what we are trying to prove!). Fix $c\in\mathbb{R}$ and consider the following polynomial:
$$
G_{c}(x) = \prod_{i<j} (x-(x_i+x_j+cx_ix_j))
$$
The coefficients of $G_{c}(x)$ are symmetric polynomials in $\{x_i\}$ with real coefficients. By Fundamental Theorem of Symmetric Polynomials, any such symmetric polynomial can be written as a some polynomial (with real coefficients) in $\sum_{i} x_i$, $\sum_{i<j} x_i x_j$, $\sum_{i<j<k} x_i x_j x_k$, …, $x_1x_2\cdots x_d$. But these elementary symmetric functions are precisely the coefficients of $f$, which are real. To see this, expand $f(x)=(x-x_1)\cdots(x-x_d)$. So the conclusion is that $G_{c}(x)$ has real coefficients. Now, $\deg(G_{c})={d\choose 2}=d(d-1)/2=2^{n-1} (2^{n}m-1)$. Since $2^{n}m-1$ is odd, we can apply induction hypothesis to deduce that $G_{c}$ has a root $z_{c}\in\mathbb{C}$. So $z_{c}=x_i+x_j+cx_ix_j$ for some pair of index $(i, j)$ with $i<j$. But number of such indices is finite, while there are infinitely many choices for $c\in\mathbb{R}$. Hence, we can find distinct $c$ and $d$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that 
$$
z_{c}=x_i+x_j+cx_ix_j \ \ \ \ \ z_{d}=x_i+x_j+dx_ix_j 
$$
Since $c\neq d$, by using appropriate linear combination of these equations, it is easy to solve  for $x_i+x_j$ and $x_ix_j$.  In other words, find complex numbers $w_1, w_2$ such that $x_i+x_j=w_1$ and $x_ix_j = w_2$. These two equations can be combined to give a quadratic equation in $x_i$. The good old quadratic formula applies and shows $x_i\in\mathbb{C}$. So we have found a root of $f$ in $\mathbb{C}$! Whew!

Comment: Wow! Thanks much for this.

Comment: My pleasure. I like this argument a lot, so writing it up was fun :)

Comment: @Prism: Just a remark: “So we have found a root of $f$ in $\mathbb {C}$!” It is not strictly speaking the case the true story being “So we have proved there exists a root of $f$ in $\mathbb {C}$!". The most of several proofs of this theorem are not constructive (it was Weierstrass who asked about a constructive one of this important theorem).

Comment: In the beginning while constructing real coefficients you surely mean $f(x)·\bar f(x)=f(x)·\overline{f(\bar x)}$.

Comment: By context, $x$ is a complex indeterminate. In your formulation, the product contains terms with factors $\bar x$ since $\overline{a_k·x^k}=\bar a_k·\bar x^k$.

Comment: @LutzL: Thanks. I corrected the post.

Comment: Actually this is the Gauss' proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra. (As a curiosity: what proof did you learn in the undergrad algebra course?)

Comment: @user26857: Well, in his book, Pierre Samuel called it "proof essentially due to Lagrange". In my undergrad algebra courses, we didn't prove FTA. So the only proofs of FTA I saw in class were from complex analysis (using Liouville, maximum modulus principle, Rouche's principle, etc…)

Comment: @Prism Well, I usually teach this in the regular algebra course for undergrads, but this may vary from an university to another. Anyway, [this file](http://math.huji.ac.il/~ehud/MH/Gauss-HarelCain.pdf) could be of some interest for you and the OP.

Comment: @user26857: Looks very interesting. And yes, I see that the file attributes the proof given in my post to Gauss's second proof from 1816.

Answer (score 2):

This proves that polynomials of degree $d$ have at most $d$ roots, not that they have exactly $d$ roots with multiplicity, which what is usually referred to as the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Comment: Would trying to continue it for the "exactly" statement involves complex analysis, Galois theory, abstract linear algebra or some other tool not normally frequented in the early years of an undergrad.?

Comment: Short answer: Basically. It's a deep fact and requires some machinery one way or another to prove it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll guess i'll miserably leave it. But,I'm don't believe this should be undergrad. Material if it's proof isn't, even if it can help with a lot of things in undergrad.

Comment: I think there is an `elementary' (in fact there are probably several) proof, but very intricate and clever due to Derksen, which appeared in the Bulletin of the AMS many years ago. This can be understood by a sophisticated undergraduate, avoids complex analysis, Galois theory etc.

Comment: There’s a proof using nothing but the fact that a polynomial of odd degree over $\Bbb R$ has at least one real root, but I no longer know it.

Comment: @Lubin: you may be thinking of Lagrange's proof http://www.jstor.org/stable/27642032?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: @Lubin: I posted an answer to that effect. I didn't see Rob's comment at the time.

Comment: @Prism, my memory is totally unreliable, but this does not look like the proof I saw (about 60 years ago), though I *do* recall that it involved the Fundamental Theorem on Symmetric Functions.